# Compiling Mongo c driver example program

Tags: c, mongodb, gcc, compilation, mongo-c-driver

I am beginning to learn about using the mongo-c-driver, but I have been having compilation issues when I run

```
gcc -g -Wall -Werror -Isrc --std=c99 mongo-c-driver/src/*.c -I mongo-c-driver/src/ intro.c -lmongoc
```

I have already looked over the other stackoverflow post, found here [cannot compile mongo-c-driver example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934980/cannot-compile-mongo-c-driver-example) , it did not help. Here is the output from my compiler

```
mongo-c-driver/src/bcon.c:37:12: error: ‘bcon_error’ defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]
mongo-c-driver/src/bcon.c:378:13: error: ‘bcon_json_print’ defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
mongo-c-driver/src/env.c: In function ‘mongo_env_socket_connect’:
mongo-c-driver/src/env.c:319:21: error: storage size of ‘ai_hints’ isn’t known
mongo-c-driver/src/env.c:340:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘getaddrinfo’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
mongo-c-driver/src/env.c:342:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘gai_strerror’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
mongo-c-driver/src/env.c:347:60: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
mongo-c-driver/src/env.c:348:36: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
mongo-c-driver/src/env.c:348:55: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
mongo-c-driver/src/env.c:348:76: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
mongo-c-driver/src/env.c:354:45: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
mongo-c-driver/src/env.c:354:62: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
mongo-c-driver/src/env.c:368:20: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
mongo-c-driver/src/env.c:381:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘freeaddrinfo’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
mongo-c-driver/src/env.c:319:21: error: unused variable ‘ai_hints’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
intro.c: In function ‘main’:
intro.c:9:7: error: enumeration value ‘MONGO_CONN_SUCCESS’ not handled in switch [-Werror=switch]
intro.c:9:7: error: enumeration value ‘MONGO_CONN_ADDR_FAIL’ not handled in switch [-Werror=switch]
intro.c:9:7: error: enumeration value ‘MONGO_CONN_BAD_SET_NAME’ not handled in switch [-Werror=switch]
intro.c:9:7: error: enumeration value ‘MONGO_CONN_NO_PRIMARY’ not handled in switch [-Werror=switch]
intro.c:9:7: error: enumeration value ‘MONGO_IO_ERROR’ not handled in switch [-Werror=switch]
intro.c:9:7: error: enumeration value ‘MONGO_SOCKET_ERROR’ not handled in switch [-Werror=switch]
intro.c:9:7: error: enumeration value ‘MONGO_READ_SIZE_ERROR’ not handled in switch [-Werror=switch]
intro.c:9:7: error: enumeration value ‘MONGO_COMMAND_FAILED’ not handled in switch [-Werror=switch]
intro.c:9:7: error: enumeration value ‘MONGO_WRITE_ERROR’ not handled in switch [-Werror=switch]
intro.c:9:7: error: enumeration value ‘MONGO_NS_INVALID’ not handled in switch [-Werror=switch]
intro.c:9:7: error: enumeration value ‘MONGO_BSON_INVALID’ not handled in switch [-Werror=switch]
intro.c:9:7: error: enumeration value ‘MONGO_BSON_NOT_FINISHED’ not handled in switch [-Werror=switch]
intro.c:9:7: error: enumeration value ‘MONGO_BSON_TOO_LARGE’ not handled in switch [-Werror=switch]
intro.c:9:7: error: enumeration value ‘MONGO_WRITE_CONCERN_INVALID’ not handled in switch [-Werror=switch]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

### Update

Also, if I decide to run

```
gcc --std=c99 -Wall intro.c -lmongoc
```

my program will compile, but will give me the error

```
$ ./a.out 
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libmongoc.so.0.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: While using `-Werror` is good practice, not all projects do this.  Are you sure that the mongo-c-driver source is expected to build without warnings?

Comment: It should be correct, I have followed all the instructions on http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/tutorial.html

Comment: I can't see anything on that page which suggests the code is expected to build without warnings.  Their recommended invocation of gcc omits `-Wall -Werror`.  I suspect the warnings you're seeing are expected so you'll need to either remove `-Werror` from your command line or fix the warnings yourself and submit a patch.  (The latter approach will likely be quite frustrating.  Unless you persuade a project to start enabling warnings and treating them as errors, they'll likely accidentally add more warnings with each commit.)

Comment: Wouldn't it be expected to build since this is their tutorial on how to use the project?

Comment: It may well build if you use the compiler command they suggest.  You've added extra flags (`-Wall -Werror`) so aren't using the recommended build command.  Why not try building without these extra flags?

Comment: It refuses to compile, and returns all of the pointer errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to fix this issue, at least in fedora 18, is to run the following commands

```
su -c "echo /usr/local/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mongoc.conf"
su -c "ldconfig"
```

which correctly link the libraries from mongo-c-driver.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this example will not compile, but if I copy the src directory and make a lib directory, where all of the compiled binaries for the driver lie, the I can compile the program using

```
gcc --std=c99 -o test_program -Llib/ -Isrc/ test.c lib/libmongoc.a
```

where the directories are setup as follows

```
--test.c
--lib
|---libbson.a
|---libbson.so
|---libmongoc.a
|---libmongoc.so
--src
|---bcon.h
|---bon.c
|---env.c
|---env.h
|---etc.
```